# How to change font color in NSTextView?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, colors, textview

Ive been searching everywhere, but I cant find a solution how to change the font color in the NSTextView? There is of course an option in Xcode / Interface Builder, but I doesnt change the color, when compiled. The background color does change though.
Do I have to subclass the TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:-

```
(IBAction) colorTest: (id) sender{ 
[mText insertText: @"red" color: [NSColor redColor]]; 
[mText insertText: @" " color: [NSColor blackColor]]; 
[mText insertText: @"green" color: [NSColor greenColor]]; 
[mText insertText: @" " color: [NSColor blackColor]]; 
[mText insertText: @"blue" color: [NSColor blueColor]]; 
[mText insertText: @" " color: [NSColor blackColor]]; 
}
```

or you try this to set it to default color like this:-

```
 NSFont* font = <whatever>;
[textView setFont: font];
```

or

```
 [[myNSTextView textStorage] setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:11]];
```